# Cirq: Any interesting introductory level example using 2D grid of qubits?

Tags: cirq

*I have already asked this question on [reddit.com/r/QuantumComputing](https://www.reddit.com/r/QuantumComputing/comments/dk8lsk/cirq_any_interesting_introductory_level_example).*

Cirq supports to create quantum circuits composed by qubits having 2D grid structure.

We have been preparing educational materials to teach the basics of quantum computing and quantum programming tools. I am looking for an interesting and **very basic level example** using 2D grid of qubits. It should not be more complex than superdense coding or quantum teleportation but still have some fun.

Do you know any example or do you have any idea?

*We have used Qiskit until now, and we plan to include the examples by pyQuil and Cirq. Having some good motivation would be pedagogically reasonable when including them, as we would ask the user to install and learn more than one platform.*

Thank you!

Comment: You could do a permutation of the grid, like transposing or reversing the qubits. That sort of task is more efficient on a grid than on a line. Another simple example would be a flood fill of some sort, like a CNOT from some common control to all other qubits or computing the parity of all the qubits.

Comment: are you looking for code, or just for some fun physical example to implement?

Comment: @user2723984: some examples or ideas. We will create the material and codes.

Comment: @CraigGidney: Nice ideas for practicing on the grid. Thank you!

Comment: do you know about the surface code? You could implement one qubit using a grid with that, but maybe it's too complex?

Comment: @user2723984: I have seen a previous post about it, but, as you also remarked, it is too complex.